# What do these strange values of padding mean in Microsoft's Fluent-react library?

Tags: fluentui-react

In this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/stack), the section [***Vertical Stack - Gap and Padding Sizes***], click [***Show code***], then at lines 30, 34, 38, etc. I see some strange values of padding (and some of childrenGap) like 'm 40px', 's1', 's2', 'l1', and have no idea what they mean or where they are defined.

I tried to play around its code and not sure where to go next after the line 9 in this [file](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/cbc0b9a2f9b569eeabd7bba3812002edcca948e8/packages/react-internal/src/components/Stack/StackUtils.ts).

Could someone please point me to their definition or document?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging, I found this in the [Fluent source code](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/theme/src/spacing/DefaultSpacing.ts).  I'm not confident that's what's in play here, but circumstantial evidence points in that direction.

```
export const DefaultSpacing: ISpacing = {
  s2: '4px',
  s1: '8px',
  m: '16px',
  l1: '20px',
  l2: '32px',
};
```